Controlling On/off of WL-134 Module with ESP32
I want to control on/off of WL-134 RFID module from GPIO of ESP32. WL-134 requires 9V, 140mA on its input so Basically I want to control 9V input from GPIO of ESP32 when I dont want to use RFID module. I am thinking of using NPN transistor for switching but I am not sure if it will work or not? Any Block diagram or sketch will help me understand.
Basically i dont want it to be on all the time to save power. So I thought to turn it on whenever I need to

What are your variants of using NPN transistor to accomplish this task?

i was thinking of S8050 as i use it for signals switching but never tried for power switching

Can we chat at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/156379/wl-134-and-esp32 ?

If the RFID module requires 9V, but your control signal is 3.3V only, a simple BJT like S5080 won't do the job.
One correct way is to use so-called HIGH-SIDE switch with Enable function, check Digi-Key or Mouser parametric search for "Power Distribution Switches and Load Drivers, something like TPS22810 (with VIN=9V).

The other way is to use some low-power reed relay similar to Meder SIL03-1A72-71D. Control coil of this relay can be driven directly from ESP I/O, other relays might need an extra transistor to operate.
